# foreign keys equivalents of laravel relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

so i have those models

```
// Curso.php
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trienio');
}

// Trienio.php
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Curso');
}

public function oe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\OE');
}

public function aluno()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Aluno');
}

// Oe.php
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trienio');
}

// Aluno.php
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Trienio');
}

public function pap()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PAP');
}

// Pap.php
public function aluno()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Aluno');
}

public function video()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Video');
}

// Video.php
public function pap()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pap');
}
```

and i'm having trouble "converting" those to sql foreign keys. can anybody give me insight on what the foreign keys equivalents will be considering those eloquent relationships? ty in advance

p.s - i can provide more details if needed.

p.s2 - what i REALLY want to know is how i should structure the fields, the sql foreign keys and the constraints based on those eloquent relationships. and how do i that ?

Comment: You could log the queries done by your migrations and see what they are.

Comment: answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever you have hasMany relation, please specify the foreign key used. as follows

```
// Curso.php
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trienio', 'curso_id');
}
```

this means you have one to many relation ship between `Curso` and `Trienio`, but the table trienio must have a field as `curso_id` (If you want default implementation, no need to establish hard relationship using SQL foreign key constraints) By default this relation will work. 
And in `belongsTo` you dont need to specify the key (Optional).

To fetch the data from Curso

```
$curso = Curso::find(1);
$trienio = $curso->trienio;
```

At the trienio side, its okay

```
// Trienio.php
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Curso');
}
```

Similarly for all other.
**Note:** If you do like this for **Curso** and **Trienio** (one to many), the table of **Trienio** model must have `curso_id` field and by default relationship will work without doing anything at SQL side.

**Update:Using SQL, modify table of Trienio model.**

```
ALTER TABLE trienios MODIFY COLUMN curso_id INT NOT NULL,
 ADD CONSTRAINT trienios_curso_id_fk
 FOREIGN KEY(curso_id)
 REFERENCES Curso(id);
```

Using Schema builder (Migration Files) [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#foreign-keys)

```
$table->foreign('curso_id')
      ->references('id')->on('curso')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

You can specify the cascade rule.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, but i didn't really wanted this. what i wanted to know was how to structure the foreign keys and constraints in the sql database based on the eloquent relationships i've shown. i guess i didnt express myself well

Comment: see my updates on this post, you can create the relationship and the foreign key using laravel schema builder at the time of table creations(run migration) and if you want to use SQL then you can run SQL statement on SQL server. but as soon as you establish relation using ORM its no need to hard relation using SQL.